# Alter UICollectionViewFlowLayout so that the cells appear from the bottom up

Tags: ios, swift

The default `UICollctionViewFlowLayout` does this:

```
|-------|
|A      |
|-------| 
|B      |
|-------|
|C      |
|-------|
|D      |
|-------|
|       |
|_______| // Notice the gap here at the bottom, where all cells start from the top
```

However I want to do this:

```
________
|       |
|       | // The gap is at the top now, and the cells should grow from the bottom
|-------|
|A      |
|-------| 
|B      |
|-------|
|C      |
|-------|
|D      |
|_______|
```

How can I alter the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to do this?

Comment: You can also play with the contentOffset, why may be faster.

Comment: @Larme true! I'd completely overlooked that, let me give it a whirl.